# How to do a bar graphic with multiple columns out of an excel archive?

Tags: r, excel, bar-chart, bioinformatics

How can I make a graphic bar using barplot() or ggplopt() of an excel archive that has 83 columns?
I need to plot every column that has a >0 value on ich raw. (ich column represents a gene function and I need to know how many functions there is on ich cluster).

Iwas trying this,but it didn't work:

```r
ggplot(x, aes(x=Cluster, y=value, fill=variable)) +
  geom_bar(stat="bin", position="dodge") +
  theme_bw() +
  ylab("Funções no cluster") +
  xlab("Cluster") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Blues")
```

Link to the excel:
https://github.com/annabmarques/GenesCorazon/blob/master/AllclusPathwayEDIT.xlsx

Comment: Welcome to SO, Anna! It is much preferred for questions to be self-contained and reproducible. While some questions may require it, usually links to external files are discouraged in lieu of putting usable (unambiguous) data from either `data.frame(...)` (building data randomly/programmatically) or the output from `dput(x, 20)` (where "20" is a sufficient number of rows to be able to adequately represent your issue). Some people are averse to downloading random files, especially something that is not raw-text (such as CSV, TSV, JSON, etc).

Answer (score 0):

What about a heatmap? A rough example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(openxlsx)

data <- read.xlsx("AllclusPathwayEDIT.xlsx")

data <- data %>%
  mutate(cluster_nr = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -c(Cluster, cluster_nr),
               names_to = "observations",
               values_to = "value") %>%
  mutate(value = as.factor(value))

ggplot(data, aes(x = cluster_nr, y = observations, fill = value)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues")
```

Given the large number of observations consider breaking this up into multiple charts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to understand exactly what you're trying to do. Is this what you're trying to achieve?

```
#install.packages("readxl")
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)
read_excel("AllclusPathwayEDIT.xlsx") %>% 
  pivot_longer(!Cluster, names_to = "gene_counts", values_to = "count") %>% 
  mutate(Cluster = as.factor(Cluster)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Cluster, y = count, fill = gene_counts)) +
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat = "identity") +
  theme(legend.position = "right",
        legend.key.size = unit(0.4,"line"),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 7),
        legend.title = element_blank()) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(ncol = 1))
ggsave(filename = "example.pdf", height = 20, width = 35, units = "cm")
```

[image]